# how to put listview in quickaction in Android?

Tags: android, listview, customization, quickaction

I am Developing news Application,in which i added quickaction menu for press button and here my problem is i want to disply listview within that quickaction,So any one could help me to create custom quick action

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D) is the brilliant tutorial and source code for quick action.After exploring the code you can add list in quick anction.

Comment: hey i want to add Listview in QuickAction Dailog ? have u got any solution